# How to print string array in reverse order in python

Tags: python, linux

Suppose that the string which I want to print it: `192.168.1.1`
Then the output which I need is: `1.1.168.192`

I use this command but it didn't help me:

```
str = array[]
str1 = str[::-1]
print(str1)
```

The output is: `1.1.861.291`
So I didn't want this way.

Comment: `str = array[]` does not look like Python to me. What are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: It's also going to be more complex than just reversing the whole string, you'll have to split and reverse each chunk of the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `split('.')` your string to convert to a list, then reverse it using `[::-1]` and join it again adding the `.`

```
mystring = "192.168.1.1"
print '.'.join(mystring.split('.')[::-1])
```

Output:

```
1.1.168.192
```

Comment: You can also reverse using [**`reversed`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed).